# If I need to set width to text width, how can I restore it later?

Tags: lengths

What is the syntax for storing some width in order to change it temporarily and then restore to the original?

Example:

```
%save length here
\setlength\somewidth{\textwidth}
some text
\begin{someenvironment}
more text
\end{someenvironment}
%restore length here
```

Comment: Put a `{...}` pair around your whole instruction or set the with inside your environment.

Comment: Can I do something like `\setlength\anotherlength{\somelength}` then reverse that? Or do I need to somehow define `\anotherlength` first?

Comment: Lengths have to be defined first anyway, but you don't need to use this explicit setting. Just use groups!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lengths are group safe, i.e. any change inside a `{...}` will be restricted to that group, unless explicitly made global. For example, lengths being set in tabular cell are changed in that cell only, in the next cells the value is not affected by this!

Either you place a `{...}` (or a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair) or use the setting inside of the environment (if possible) --  environments form groups as well.

Third possibility: Define a scratch width with `\newlength` and either say `\setlength{\helperwidth}{\somewidth}` or the more `TeX` - like `\helperwidth=\somewidth` or even shorter: `\helperwidth\somewidth`, if really needed.

The definition of an extra length (or using another one that is not needed at the moment) has its advantages if the old definition ('value') must be used for some extra calculations etc.

The 'right' method depends on the actual requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\somewidth}
\newlength{\helperwidth}% Just for fun

\newenvironment{someenvironment}{%
Width is \the\somewidth%

}{}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\somewidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{someenvironment}
more text
\setlength\somewidth{0.5\textwidth}
Now width is \the\somewidth%

\end{someenvironment}
Outside the width is \the\somewidth

Or using a group:

{%
\setlength{\somewidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{someenvironment}
Now width is \the\somewidth%

\end{someenvironment}
}%
Outside of the group the width is \the\somewidth

\helperwidth=\somewidth
% Or \helperwidth\somewidth
\setlength\somewidth{0.75\textwidth}
\begin{someenvironment}
Now width is \the\somewidth%

\end{someenvironment}
Outside of the environment the width is \the\somewidth
\setlength{\somewidth}{\helperwidth}

Now restoring the width: \the\somewidth



\end{document}
```

[image]

The same group feature is true for `TeX` count registers -- they are group safe, however `LaTeX` counters are **not** group safe!